# Raster as Attribute Field Error

Tags: arcmap, raster, sql, error, fields-attributes

I'm using Arc 10.1. I am creating a parcel inventory where I would like to have a photo of the property attached as an attribute and view-able with an HTML popup. I have a polygon feature class built in my geodatabase. I created a Photo Field with data type as raster. I can load a photo while in an edit session of ArcMap but when I chose save edits I get an SQL error that looks something like this:

"An invalid SQL statement was used [fras_blk_MyPropertyTable]
 An invalid SQL statement was used [SELECT * fras_blk_MyPropertyTable WHERE rasterband_id in()]"

Any thoughts?

Comment: What's your data source type is?

Comment: The photos I am trying to load are Jpegs

Comment: hmm, I cannot reproduce it. What geodatabase type are you using? Local Geodatabase or ArcSDE?

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the help, I'll try to give you a little more background.
- File geodatabase local
- Geodatabase is setup to be managed 
- Polygon feature class was created from aniImported shapefile, once it was imported as a feature class I added the Photo field with data type raster
- Some times when I first try to save edits it gives me a geometry error, then every time after that it gives my the SQL statement listed above

Comment: - images are small, 1 mb or less
- The folder where I am loading the images from is located in the same directory as the geodatabase

Again I appreciate the help, I have a feeling that Geometery error might be the key. I just have no idea what could be causing it, its just an attribute I am adding, not another record/feature.

Comment: So, can you edit or add Feature without adding Raster Field?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Have you already solve it ?

Comment: I can edit everything and save those edits except when I have loaded a picture to photo field. If take the picture out I can save edits again. very strange I know

Comment: Forget my last comment. I can calculate fields still. But i can not edit anything in editor (like delete a node and save). This happens as soon as I add a raster field and load the first image. If i then remove the raster field, I can again edit and save.

Comment: New update. If i create the raster field as Unmanaged, I can add and save photos. Works with rasters imported to my geodatabase and stored outside. So why would the managed aspect make it crash?

Comment: Carlos - I haven't figured out how to fix this but I have away that works, maybe it will work for you. Create an attachment table for your feature class and load your photos to that. Link will walk you through. http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Enabling_attachments/001t000003vt000000/

Comment: If this is still an issue, rather than opening a [duplicate question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60578/raster-attribute-field-error), can you please list your exact steps (step-by-step) here (in the body of your original Question) so that we can try to reproduce it, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Problem solved, it was an ESRI Error, after talking with ESRI Support they said that installing service pack one should fix it and it did. They only had 4 records of this happening and they weren't quite sure what was causing it. But any how Service Pack 1 does the trick. – ACrain 1 min ago edit